# Javascript problem regarding data fetch from backend and represnt on frontend

Tags: javascript, react-native, web, frontend, backend

Is it possible to fetch data from backend and show it in my website frontend using HTML CSS and JavaScript??

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [mcve]. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Use `react-native-render-html` library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-render-html